# Bootstrap select picker with angularjs ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, bootstrap-selectpicker

I need a multi select for my form and I m using the bootstrap select picker but my select option data is loaded from API dynamically and I using ng-repeat to show the option in the select tag. But my select doesnt show up any options. May i know what wrong with my code?

If i use the default html5 multiple select it can show all the data rows.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="inputUserPermission" size="10" multiple required>
       <option ng-repeat="salesPersonInSoaps in salesPersonInSoap" value="{{salesPersonInSoaps.FirstName}}">{{salesPersonInSoaps.email}}</option>
</select>
```

Use bootstrap select picker doesnt work.

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" ng-model="inputUserPermission" multiple required>
       <option ng-repeat="salesPersonInSoaps in salesPersonInSoap" value="{{salesPersonInSoaps.FirstName}}">{{salesPersonInSoaps.email}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you share  your code where you are populating in salesPersonInSoap.

Comment: erm, actually i got data in salesPersonInSoap, i use the html5 multiple select it can show all the data row but when i add the class name (selectpicker) to the select tag because i want to use the bootstrap select picker then the multi select does not have any data already. Is it ng-repeat can not use for data which is dynamically add?

Comment: both the html code you provided are working perfectly on my local. please check your js code. or share here.

Comment: check if your api is getting the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Removing select-Multiple will fix it I suppose.

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" ng-model="inputUserPermission" multiple required>
   <option ng-repeat="salesPersonInSoaps in salesPersonInSoap" value="{{salesPersonInSoaps.FirstName}}">{{salesPersonInSoaps.email}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: OHhh...so sorry the select-Multiple i forget to delete. It is a directive ways i try for my probelm but it doesnt solve.

Comment: I think you need to refresh the select. Checkout these issues; [here](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/967) and [here](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/490)